# Segwit transaction from mixed addresses (segwit and non-segwit)

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, segregated-witness

Is it possible to have partly segwit transactions? I.e. some utxos from segwit addresses and some from non-segwit addresses.

Asking for the situation of Bitcoin core v0.15 wallet with coins in segwit and non-segwit addresses. If you send a transaction will it use one or both address types for the transaction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The right way to look at it is that every transaction input has a witness. For legacy outputs being spent, that witness is just empty.

So yes, mixed SegWit and legacy inputs are possible. SegWit transaction serialization will be used, and the witnesses for all legacy inputs will be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if a transaction input has no witness it simply puts `0x00` as its witness entry

EDIT: If you want to check out some raw transaction examples to see where exactly the `0x00` would be located inside the  raw transaction, you can look at examples of raw segwit transactions for segnet here: http://n.bitcoin.ninja/checktx